# Implement INTERFACE based functionality in reactjs to render component based on variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

How to use interface-based functionality to render components based on tab selection.

Assume I have 3 components i.e.

1. OneTimeOnlyScheduleComponent
2. DailyScheduleComponent
3. WeeklyScheduleComponent

I want to have some kind of functionality where all of these components are implementing interface `InterfaceBasedComponent`

e.g.

1. `OneTimeOnlyScheduleComponent implements InterfaceBasedComponent`
2. `DailyScheduleComponent implements InterfaceBasedComponent`
3. `WeeklyScheduleComponent implements InterfaceBasedComponent`

In ReactJS, I should be able to create an object using a factory pattern or something.

[GitHub Code](https://github.com/shantanugupta/react-scheduler/blob/main/src/components/Scheduler/Scheduler.component.jsx)
[Hosted UI](https://shantanugupta.github.io/react-scheduler/)

```
{/* TAB BUTTONS */}
<ul className="nav nav-tabs border-bottom-0" role="tablist">
{
    freqType.map(freq => {
        return (
            ![64, 128].includes(freq.key) &&
            <li key={freq.key} className="nav-item">
                <a href="#freqType1" property_name="freq_type" 
                    className={"nav-link " + (state.freq_type === freq.key ? 'active' : '')}
                    onClick={(e) => scheduleTypeChange(freq.key)}
                    data-toggle="tab" role="tab" 
                    aria-controls="freqType1" 
                    aria-selected={state.freq_type === freq.key}>
                    {freq.value}</a>
            </li>)
    })
}
</ul>
```

Based on the above code, when the user clicks on one of the tabs, the corresponding component should get generated.

```
<div className="tab-content border">
    {/* One time schedule */}
    <div className={"m-2 tab-pane fade " + (state.freq_type === 1 ? showClass : hiddenClass)} id="freqType1" role="tabpanel">
        <OneTimeOnlyScheduleComponent schedule={state} onComponentChange={commonScheduleChangeHandler} />
    </div>
    {/* Daily schedule */}
    <div className={"m-2 tab-pane fade " + (state.freq_type === 4 ? showClass : hiddenClass)} id="freqType4" role="tabpanel">
        <DailyScheduleComponent schedule={state} onComponentChange={commonScheduleChangeHandler} />
    </div>
    {/* Weekly schedule */}
    < div className={"m-2 tab-pane fade " + (state.freq_type === 8 ? showClass : hiddenClass)} id="freqType8" role="tabpanel">
        <WeeklyScheduleComponent schedule={state} onComponentChange={commonScheduleChangeHandler} />
    </div>
    {/* Monthly schedule */}
    < div className={"m-2 tab-pane fade " + (state.freq_type === 16 ? showClass : hiddenClass)} id="freqType16" role="tabpanel">
        <MonthlyScheduleComponent schedule={state} onComponentChange={commonScheduleChangeHandler} />
    </div>
    {/* Monthly relative schedule */}
    <div className={"m-2 tab-pane fade " + (state.freq_type === 32 ? showClass : hiddenClass)} id="freqType32" role="tabpanel">
        <MonthlyRelativeScheduleComponent schedule={state} onComponentChange={commonScheduleChangeHandler} />
    </div>
    {/* Yearly schedule */}
    <div className={"m-2 tab-pane fade " + (state.freq_type === 64 ? showClass : hiddenClass)} id="freqType64" role="tabpanel">
        <YearlyScheduleComponent schedule={state} onComponentChange={commonScheduleChangeHandler} />
    </div>
    {/* Year long schedule */}
    <div className={"m-2 tab-pane fade " + (state.freq_type === 128 ? showClass : hiddenClass)} id="freqType128" role="tabpanel">
        <YearLongScheduleComponent schedule={state} onComponentChange={commonScheduleChangeHandler} />
    </div>
</div>
```

Ideally, I would like to have my code simplified to use interface-based object rendering e.g. `InterfaceBasedComponent`. This interface should be able to create an object of the required component.

```
<div className="tab-content border">
{
    freqType.map(freq => {
    return (
       ![64, 128].includes(freq.key) &&                     
       <div className={"m-2 tab-pane fade " + (state.freq_type === freq.key ? showClass : hiddenClass)} 
          id={"freqType" + freq.key} 
          role="tabpanel">
          <InterfaceBasedComponent schedule={state} onComponentChange={commonScheduleChangeHandler} />
      </div>
  )}            
}
</div >
```

Comment: React favors [composition over inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html), worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I should be able to create an object using a factory pattern
> ...
> I would like to have my code simplified to use interface-based object
> rendering

but what do you *actually* want to *simplify* ? (e.g. a *factory* is not an *interface*).

#### interfaces

If you explicitly want to use interfaces, then that is not possible, because Javascript doesn't have interfaces, and so doesn't React.

(There are [interfaces in Typscript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), but I'm sure that's not what you mean)

#### factory

But you can very well use a factory function to create components:

```
const OneTimeOnlyScheduleComponent = ( props ) => {
    return <>
        <p>( specific stuff to OneTimeOnlyScheduleComponent )</p>
        { props.children }
    </>;
};

const DailyScheduleComponent = ( props ) => {
    return <>
        <p>( specific stuff to DailyScheduleComponent )</p>
        { props.children }
    </>;
};

export const ListFactory = ( props: IProps ) => {
    const { schedule } = props;

    const List = <ul>
        { schedule.list.map( item => <li key={ item.key }>{ item.value }</li> ) }
    </ul>;

    switch( schedule.type ){
        case 'onetime': return <OneTimeOnlyScheduleComponent>{ List }</OneTimeOnlyScheduleComponent>;
        case 'daily':   return <DailyScheduleComponent>{ List }</DailyScheduleComponent>;
        default:
            return 'error';
    }
};

function App(){
    const [ schedule, setSchedule ] = useState( { type: 'onetime', list: list } );

    return <div>
        <button onClick={ () => { setSchedule( { type: 'daily', list: list } ); }}>
            switch
        </button>
        <ListFactory schedule={ schedule } />
    </div>;
}
```

#### HOC

There are also [Higher-Order Components (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) in React, which maybe solve
issues more like what interfaces would do, in a sense... But I don't see how this would help you in this case.

E.g. you might have a HOC called `implementsList`, but then all your components should indeed implement the list, so you
will not get rid of the code duplication with this approach:

```
export const OneTimeOnlyScheduleComponent = implementsList(( props ) => {
    return <><p>( specific stuff to OneTimeOnlyScheduleComponent )</p>
        <ul>
            { props.list.map( item => <li key={ item.key }>{ item.value }</li> ) }
        </ul>
    </>;
});

export const DailyScheduleComponent = implementsList(( props ) => {
    return <><p>( specific stuff to DailyScheduleComponent )</p>
        <ul>
            { props.list.map( item => <li key={ item.key }>{ item.value }</li> ) }
        </ul>
    </>;
});

function implementsList(WrappedComponent) {
    return function( props ){
        return <>
            <p>type: { props.schedule.type }</p>
            <WrappedComponent list={ props.schedule.list } />
        </>;
    };
}
```

By the way: A HOC should - as a convention - be named with the prefix `with...`, so in this case the HOC would be better named `withList`,
which also represents better what the intention of using HOCs should be.